# reload only when value is changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, session-storage

I am trying to reload the browser here only when switching from one content to another.

```
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      if (props.isContentDefined)
          window.sessionStorage.setItem("isContentDef", props.contentId);
      var val = window.sessionStorage.getItem("isContentDef");
      if (val !== "" && val) {
              window.location.reload();
              window.sessionStorage.clear();
       }
    },
    [props.isContentDefined]
  );
```

when initial content is loaded -> no reload necessary.
when user switches from one content to another -> reload is necessary.

props.isContentDefined is available from backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify your 'if' condition like this by checking if session value is also different from new props value.. then reload

```
 React.useEffect(
    () => {
      if (props.isContentDefined)
      var val = window.sessionStorage.getItem("isContentDef");
      if (val !== "" && val && val !== props.isContentDefined)) {
              window.location.reload();
              window.sessionStorage.clear();
      }else
         window.sessionStorage.setItem("isContentDef", props.contentId);
    },
    [props.isContentDefined]
  );
```